# how do you declare an array of dynamic nested objects inside typescript?

Tags: typescript

The structure of an array :

```
[
  branch_a: {
    holidays: []
  },
  branch_b: {
    holidays: []
  },
]
```

where `branch_a`, `branch_b`, `...` are dynamic keys. How to declare this properly in typescript. I have tried the following:

```
type holiday_ar = Array<string>
type holiday = Record<"holidays", holiday_ar> & Record<string, holiday_ar>
```

after this i am pretty confused how to move forward.

*Note: I am still learning typescript*

Comment: Keys inside an array `[ branch_a: [], branch_b: [] ]`? Should that be keys inside an object? `{ branch_a: [], branch_b: [] }`?

Comment: @DM, i wanted to have it in such a way that, foo["branch_a"] = {}

Comment: you misunderstand what the accessor notation means. `something[key:string]` is accessing a key; it's not an array index. What you want is an Object like the answer provided

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need `type` like `HolidayArray`:

```
type HolidayArray = {
  [branch: string]: { holidays: [] }
}

const holidayArray: HolidayArray = {
  `branch1`: { holidays: [] },
  `branch2`: { holidays: [] }
}

console.log(holidayArray[`branch1`]);
```